# Using non-Fabric CA as a parent of Fabric CAs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Is it possible to use a general public CA (like DigiCert) or an arbitrary non-Fabric CA as a parent of intermediate fabric-ca-servers ? 
The official doc seems to assume that you use only Fabric CAs as parents.

The intention behind this question is to mitigate the centralized nature of a single root CA.

**Edit**: By "non-Fabric CA" I mean any implementation other than Fabric CA that can act as a CA, e.g. OpenSSL.

[image: non-Fabric CA as a root]

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  It seems very strange to me that there is no thorough documentation on this provided by the Fabric team... Surely almost all enterprise use cases will involve a non-Fabric CA for PKI.

Comment: I’ve made no progress in this so far. I guess some e terprise guys have possibly abandoned to use FabricCA and instead created the entire MSPs using non-Fabric means by mimicking FCA behavior, or some others ended up with using FabricCA only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a third-party certificate as a root (RCA) to generate an intermediate certificate (ICA). You can configure Fabric CA to use the ICA to issue peer/orderer certificates.

[Fabric CA User Guide](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#starting-the-server)

> If you want the Fabric CA server to use a CA signing certificate and key file which you provide, you must place your files in the location referenced by ca.certfile and ca.keyfile respectively. Both files must be PEM-encoded and must not be encrypted. More specifically, the contents of the CA certificate file must begin with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and the contents of the key file must begin with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and not -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----.

Checkout the sample Fabric Config file here. The properties ca.certfile, ca.keyfile and ca.chainfile have to point to the ICA before starting the CA Server.

[Sample Fabric Config File](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/serverconfig.html)